# Extra character at the end of a string in the following program?

Tags: c

This program is to take the first two words in the sentence and place them at the end and input and output as a single string.

But I am getting extra '^' at the end.

Input:

> I will go now to find the Wookiee

Expected Output:

> go now to find the Wookiee I will

Obtained Output:

> go now to find the Wookiee I will ̂

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[100], b[100], e[100];
    int c = 0, i, k = 0, j = 0;

    gets(a);
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == ' ' && j < 2)
        {
            c = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(i = c + 1; i <= strlen(a); i++)
    {
        b[k] = a[i];
        k++;
    }

    e[0] = ' ';

    for(i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    {
        e[i] = a[i - 1];
    }

    e[i]= ' ';
    strcat(b, e);
    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

> INPUT: to the people of india
>   OUTPUT: people of india to the ̂

Comment: `gets()` is **evil**, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: You should format your code correctly and use meaningful variable names instead of b,e, a etc.

Comment: for readability by us humans, it is much better to surround each expression in a compound 'if' statement with parens.   Also, using parens assures the proper order of evaluation is performed.  Few of us know all the details of the precedence of the C operators, using parens makes it clear what is to be grouped together.

Comment: Since the posted code is not commented and the variable names are meaningless, most (including me) will not bother to try and reverse engineer the code to try and determine what the posted code is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and your code worked fine in my system. This could be mainly, because you are not initializing character arrays `a,b,e` in your code and they might contain junk values. After initializing them to '0', things don't behave weirdly.
Additionally, you don't need an extra space in 'e[i]' call just before `strcat` as shown in below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  //char a[100]={0},b[100]={0},e[100]={0};
  char a[100]={0},b[100]={0},e[100]={0};
  int c=0,i,k=0,j=0;

  gets(a);
  for(i =0;i<=strlen(a);i++)
  {
    if (a[i] == ' '&& j<2)
    {
      c=i;
      j++;
    }
  }
  for(i=c+1;i<=strlen(a);i++)
  {
    b[k]=a[i];
    k++;
  }
  e[0]=' ';
  for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
  {
    e[i]=a[i-1];
  }
  //e[i]=' ';
  strcat(b,e);
  printf("[%s]\n",b);
  return 0;
}
```

*Moreover, from a secure/better programming perspective, it is always good to initialize variables while declaring them. This way we can be sure what value(s) variable contains rather then relying on OS for this.*

Answer (score 1):

you may modify your code to :

```
    ....        
    }
    e[i] = '\0';   //<-- with space i crashed here, with that i get 'get the wookies I will'
    strcat(b, e);
    printf("%s", b);
    return 0;
}
```

strings end with \0
without the \0 a stringfunction will read until the 1st \0
even if it is not your string memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour here because you are missing a NUL terminator in the `e` string that is to be appended to the string `b`.

On my computer the program actually crashed.

```
for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
{
  e[i]=a[i-1];
}

e[i] = ' ';
e[i+1] = 0;   // <<<< add this line in your code
strcat(b,e);
printf("%s",b);
return 0;
```

Comment: i+1 would lead to : 'get the wookies I will ' instead of 'get the wookies I will'. e is the end, so the space makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

This line: `e[i]= ' ';` fails to properly terminate the string of characters in `e`,

so when `printf()` is called, more characters are printed until a `\0` is encountered.

In general, this lack of a proper string termination character results in undefined behaviour which can lead to a segmentation fault event.

The symptom of this problem is the extra printed character.

There are probably other extra characters, which were not printable before a `\0` was encountered in memory.